# How to type and delete text in a pre-span-wrapped text in conteteditable div while keeping the span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to insert and delete text in a pre-span-wrapped text in content-editable div while keeping the `<span id="x">` tag?

1. In the content-editable div, if delete "kachu", `<span id="2">` would also be deleted. I want that specific tag still there even without text.`<span id="2></span>`
2. In the content-editable div, if typing in "pi" just before "kachu" to make "pikachu", `<span id="2">` would not wrap "pi". I want `<span id="2">pikachu</span>`

**HTML**

```
<div id="inputbox" style="border:1px solid lightgrey" contenteditable="true">
<span id="1">love</span> <span id="1">kachu</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording. Could you please rephrase it, especially step 1?

Comment: Grammar and spelling have been improved.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the content of the span containing 'kachu' to an empty string, but finding the span after that will be slightly difficult, since it has the same id as the other span.

```
$('#inputbox').find('span:contains("kachu")').html( '' );
```

Once "kachu" is deleted, to find the empty span you could just do the same, but change the `contains("kachu")` to `contains("")`

You should consider using different ids for your spans.  If you did intend the 2nd span to have `id="2"`, this could be: `$('#inputbox').find('#2').html( '' )` or just `$('#2').html( '' )`